# Trusty Tahr 14.04 and iPhone

Tags: files, iphone, devices

I am running 14.04 and recently removed Samba after the bug-scare. After removal of samba I was unable to play CD's. The DVD portion still works. I am also unable to transfer files from my iPhone to the computer a process which used to work.
The iPhone senses the computer and asks the 'Trust' quewtion and an lsusb command in the terminal window shows the iPhone, but it is not visible in Places, Network or Computer.

content of proc/mounts-

rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=4020164k,nr_inodes=1005041,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=806172k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,relatime,size=4k,mode=755 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=102400k,mode=755 0 0
none /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,relatime 0 0
systemd /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,name=systemd 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0

Comment: Please post the output of cat /proc/mounts

Comment: Sorry, I am not very linux-literate. Can you specify the command to output the info you're requesting?

Comment: cat /proc/mounts in the terminal

Comment: I entered it above.